# Refactoring two functions fails

Tags: c#

I have two methods: one that handles updating pictures, and one that resizes pictures and draws a rectangle.

```
public void updatePicture()
{
    if (imageList.SelectedItem == null) return;

    /*String fileName = imageList.SelectedItem.ToString();
    var currentFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(imageList.SelectedItem.ToString());

    pictureBox1.Load(fileName); This code is moved to resizeImage*/

    resizeImage(false, true);
    //drawRect(); It works if I enable this code
}
```

However, I'm trying to move everything over to resizeImage():

```
private void resizeImage(Boolean draw, Boolean update)
{
    if (!isValid()) return;

    if (update) 
    {
        String fileName = imageList.SelectedItem.ToString();
        var currentFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(imageList.SelectedItem.ToString());
        pictureBox1.Load(fileName);
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

    if (bitmap.Width < pictureBox1.Width && bitmap.Height < pictureBox1.Height)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
        return;
    }

    int width, height;

    float percentWidth = (float)pictureBox1.Width / (float)bitmap.Width;
    float percentHeight = (float)pictureBox1.Height / (float)bitmap.Height;
    float percent = percentHeight < percentWidth ? percentHeight : percentWidth;

    width = Convert.ToInt32(bitmap.Width * percent);
    height = Convert.ToInt32(bitmap.Height * percent);

    Bitmap cropBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(cropBitmap);

    g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
    g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
    g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

    g.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, cropBitmap.Width, cropBitmap.Height);
    pictureBox1.Image = cropBitmap;

    if (draw) 
    {
        drawRect();
    }
}
```

In this state it won't work, but to make it work, I simply call the drawRect() method within the updatePicture() method, which is basically just moving code. I'm not calling it at different times either.

Here is my drawRect() method:

```
private void drawRect()
{
    pictureBox1.Refresh();
    pictureBox1.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(pen, cropX, cropY, cropW, cropH);
}
```

Anyone able to see my mistake?

Comment: Hopefully if anyone ever Googles "I'm confused" they'll end up here.  edit: This was a better joke before Hogan fixed your title.

Comment: You should edit your title to get us an idea of your problem

Comment: @Antiga - I appreciate the joke.

Comment: pictureBox1.Refresh() is only called in drawRect() it looks like?

Comment: Looks like you're resizing your image to fit the pictureBox1 height and width. Why can't you just use the `PictureBox.SizeMode` property and set it to `StretchImage` to achieve the same result?

Comment: Figured out the problem, and @DarienPardinas I use it in case the picture is bigger than the achievable pictureBox size to keep the width and height ratio of the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps?

```
    if (bitmap.Width < pictureBox1.Width && bitmap.Height < pictureBox1.Height)
    {

        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;

        // add this line...
        pictureBox1.Refresh();

        return;
    }
```

and maybe also down below...

```
    pictureBox1.Image = cropBitmap;
    // add this line...
    pictureBox1.Refresh();
```

Maybe you see what I'm doing... calling refresh in all cases.

Comment: This wasn't the problem but it helped me solve it. When it checks if the width and the height is less that the pictureBox's width and height, it doesn't draw.. Thank you :)

Comment: @adfje - nice... glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (bitmap.Width < pictureBox1.Width && bitmap.Height < pictureBox1.Height)
    {

        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;

        return;
    }
```

This bit of code returns if the statement is true, and doesn't draw.

I changed the resizeImage method to this:

```
        private void resizeImage(Boolean draw, Boolean update)
    {

        if (!isValid()) return;

        if (update) 
        {

            String fileName = imageList.SelectedItem.ToString();
            var currentFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(imageList.SelectedItem.ToString());

            pictureBox1.Load(fileName);

        }

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
        bool needsCrop = true;

        if (bitmap.Width < pictureBox1.Width && bitmap.Height < pictureBox1.Height)
        {

            pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
            needsCrop = false;

        }

        if (needsCrop)
        {

            int width, height;

            float percentWidth = (float)pictureBox1.Width / (float)bitmap.Width;
            float percentHeight = (float)pictureBox1.Height / (float)bitmap.Height;
            float percent = percentHeight < percentWidth ? percentHeight : percentWidth;

            width = Convert.ToInt32(bitmap.Width * percent);
            height = Convert.ToInt32(bitmap.Height * percent);

            Bitmap cropBitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(cropBitmap);

            g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

            g.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, cropBitmap.Width, cropBitmap.Height);
            pictureBox1.Image = cropBitmap;

        }

        if (draw) { drawRect(); }
    }
```

Sorry for wasting your time :/